# Nautilus : Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)

Tags: 20.04, nautilus

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

When starting nautilus (from the desktop, or any app using the file system), the process hangs for several seconds before opening the UI.

When starting from terminal, the process hangs, I then get the following error

```
Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)
```

Right after that, the UI finally opens.

I ran `journalctl`, and around the time I started the process there was the following entries:

```
Jan 06 17:34:00 <some-name> kernel: sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware boot complete
Jan 06 17:34:00 <some-name> kernel: sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
Jan 06 17:33:55 <some-name> systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jan 06 17:33:55 <some-name> dbus-daemon[1112]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jan 06 17:33:54 <some-name> systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jan 06 17:33:54 <some-name> dbus-daemon[1112]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.278' (uid=1000 pid=27483 comm="nautilus " label="unconfined")
Jan 06 17:33:29 <some-name> systemd[2658]: Failed to start Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Jan 06 17:33:29 <some-name> systemd[2658]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan 06 17:33:29 <some-name> systemd[2658]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 06 17:33:29 <some-name> systemd[27492]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor: Permission denied
Jan 06 17:33:29 <some-name> systemd[27492]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
Jan 06 17:33:29 <some-name> systemd[2658]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Jan 06 17:33:29 <some-name> dbus-daemon[2672]: [session uid=1000 pid=2672] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.466' (uid=1000 pid=27483 comm="nautilus " label="unconfined")
Jan 06 17:33:23 <some-name> kernel: sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: firmware boot complete
Jan 06 17:33:23 <some-name> kernel: sof-audio-pci 0000:00:1f.3: error: no reply expected, received 0x0
Jan 06 17:33:15 <some-name> systemd[2658]: Started VTE child process 27467 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 26676.
```

I believe the issue is related in particular to these errors:

```
Jan 06 17:33:29 <some-name> systemd[27492]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor: Permission denied
Jan 06 17:33:29 <some-name> systemd[27492]: gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
```

Running `sudo nautilus` starts normally.

Any idea why nautilus would require some special permissions to startup ?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the permissions of the `/usr/libexec/` files, it seemed that `gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor` was the only one without execution permissions.

So `chmod +x /usr/libexec/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor` solved my issue

Comment: Thanks it solves my issue. Nautilus start was so slow.